# Query condition with calculated field

Tags: php, sql, symfony, query-builder

I would like to perform a request considering one of the field is calculated (distance).

I've got something like this

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->andWhere('p.isPublicPlace = :classic')
    ->andWhere('p.titlePlace LIKE :search OR p.categoryPlace LIKE :search')
    ->andWhere('p.categoryPlace LIKE :categoryPlace')
```

This is working.

Now I will add some filter after a distance calculation

```
$dist = "ACOS( SIN( RADIANS(latitude))* SIN( RADIANS('.$user_lat.')) + COS( RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS('.$user_lat.')) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS('.$user_lng.'))) * 6380) as distance";


$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('p')
    ->select($dist)
    ->andWhere('p.isPublicPlace = :classic')
    ->andWhere('p.titlePlace LIKE :search OR p.categoryPlace LIKE :search')
    ->andWhere('p.categoryPlace LIKE :categoryPlace')
    ->having('distance' < ':maxDistance')
    ->orderBy('distance')
```

But this is not working I have an error message on the having line

> (1/2) ContextErrorException
>   Warning: get_class() expects parameter 1 to be object, boolean given

Pretty sure I'm doing all wrong but I don't know how it can be done.

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: Looks like an error on this like `->having('distance' < ':maxDistance')`, the < should be in between the quotes as well, as now its comparing the two strings.

Comment: Damn, indeed, but looks like there is still an issue with the request `SELECT ACOS( SIN( RADIANS(latitude))* SIN( RADIANS('.6.')) + COS( RADIANS(latitude)) * COS(RADIANS('.6.')) * COS(RADIANS(longitude) - RADIANS('.5.'))) * 6380) as distance FROM AppBundle\Entity\Place p WHERE p.isPublicPlace = :classic AND (p.titlePlace LIKE :search OR p.categoryPlace LIKE :search) AND p.categoryPlace LIKE :categoryPlace HAVING distance < :maxDistance ORDER BY distance ASC`

Comment: One `)` to many?

Comment: Indeed my bad, but still the issue remains :(

Comment: Actually here is it; he don't know acos : Expected known function, got 'ACOS

Comment: No [ACOS](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_acos.asp)?  Not MySql or MariaDb then? So what RDBMS does it connect to then?

Comment: There was some inport missing in order to do it with symfony. and it's MySql